# checking session with jquery from php script then saving the item clicked to mysql database and updating the label which has been clicked

Tags: php, jquery

hi I am trying to saving to save item into my sql database I have 3 functions

```
/* the function below checks if a session is pressent using jquery ajax call to php script */


function checkSess(){
                         $.ajax({
                         url: "check_s.php",
                         cache: false,
                         success: function(data){
                                                processDetails1(data)
                                                }
                                 });
                     }


<?php
session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION['flipmode']))
{ 

    echo "u";
}
 else {
    echo "n";
}

?>


/* the function below checks if value from checkSess() is true or false */


function processDetails1(info){

              if(info==='u'){

                  return true;
              }
               else{
                    return false;
                }
           }





/* the function below checks if value from checks all data then saves to database and changes label if the result from processDetails1 and if true is returned then changes label details and if it returns false should open dialog*/


$('.savepropertycon').live('click', function() {
                var chekH = checkSess();
                if(chekH===true){
                     $.get("saveprop.php", { pid: saveId },
                            function(data){
                    $('#dialog-message').dialog('open');
                                $('#pro').html(data);
                                return false; 
                                        });


                var saveCurrentId = $(this).attr('id');

                    jQuery("label", this).html('saved');
                    $(this).removeClass();
                    $(this).removeAttr('href');
                    $(this).addClass("savedone");
                    jQuery("img", this).remove();


                }
                else {

                    $('.dialogsign').dialog('open');

                }




                return false;
            });
```

The problem I have is the above keeps and returning false I have tried to debug with firebug and var chekH is coming back as undifined. Please could somebody help thank you.

Comment: You should clean up your code example in the post.. too much spaces and hard to browse.

Comment: soooooo much white space

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to save a label, I would recommend [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable), a jquery plugin.  It will do most of the work for you.  So then your javascript would look like:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
       type: edit
     });
 });
```

Your html should look like:

```
<span class="edit" id="tableid">Text</span><br />
<span class="edit" id="anothertableid">Some Text</span>
```

Your php would look like:
save.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"]))
exit();
#INCLUDE MYSQL CONNECTION
$type = $_POST["type"];
if ($type == "edit")
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id"]);
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["value"]);
    $sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `value`='$value' WHERE `id`='$id';";
    $result = mysql_query ($sql);
    //echo $result;
}
?>
```

The php checks that the session `loggedin` if it is set, and true then it will update `table` with the id of the label's id with the new value.  Make sure to include the database connection.

Comment: Firstly mazzzzz thanks for editing my post.
I dont want to save a lable what I want to do is save details of a certain iteam in a list to the database. On sucess of the iteam being saved to the database for the link button to be changed to save.